# How to assign an Item with an ID when uploading and be able to edit , delete RecyclerView item when retrieving from Firestore

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

i am trying to upload an item with a unique id and be able to edit or delete the same item that has its corresponding id when using a recyclerView. In the code below i used "name" to apply updates to a particular item that has a corresponding name , the limitation is that some items may carry the same name so it will affect those items. Here is there snippet :

```
 editBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            fStore.collection("images").whereEqualTo("userId",fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>()  {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < Objects.requireNonNull(task.getResult()).size(); i++) {
                            if (Objects.requireNonNull(task.getResult().getDocuments().get(i).getString("name")).equals(shoeNameString)) {
                                task.getResult().getDocuments().get(i).getReference().update("name", shoeName.getText().toString());
                                task.getResult().getDocuments().get(i).getReference().update("description", shoeDescription.getText().toString());
                                task.getResult().getDocuments().get(i).getReference().update("price", shoeFullDescription.getText().toString());
                                Intent intent = new Intent(display_shoes.this, MainActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

**Saving To Firestore Method**

Here I tried to use UUID then i realized that oh snap it generates a unique id and there is there no how i can generate a variable will contain the same ID as the one in firestore.

```
private void SavingToFirestore(String url){

    String uniqueID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

   // String id = f.getCurrentUser().getUid();


    Map<String,String> userMap = new HashMap<>();

    userMap.put("userId",user_id);
    userMap.put("name",name);
    userMap.put("price",price);
    userMap.put("description",description);
    userMap.put("image",downloadUrl.toString());
    userMap.put("id",uniqueID);
    firebaseFirestore.collection("images").add(userMap)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                    itemName.setText("");
                    itemPrice.setText("");
                    itemDescription.setText("");
                    itemImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.itemphoto);
                    Toast.makeText(AddItem.this,"Item Upload successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(AddItem.this,MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }


            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(AddItem.this,"Error : "+e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

**Firestore Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: I really dont have any errors i think its all about logic , i tried to generate a uniqueUUID when uploading the item then i realized that there is no way am going to get a matching UUID when retrieving the item

Comment: You need to store id for each product in Firestore as well. In your recyclerview clickListerner get id of that object and update it accordingly.

Comment: @FahadBinAsif How ? i dont want the user to enter the id , i tried with UUID but its unique i tried to get the same UUID it crushed

Comment: @jayCoder Users dont enter id. Generate a UUID like this String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString(); and put it along other properties while saving data in Firestore.

Comment: @FahadBinAsif then how will i get the same UUID for that particular , please see my second code snippet i tried it and it kept on crushing

Comment: @jayCoder it is crashing because in Firestore all products dont have id key in it as you just added the line of code. So first update the products with id key in it. And dont update a single product using loop like you did in your above code. Try to use clickListener for recyclerview that will return selected object and update it.

Comment: @FahadBinAsif In the adapter i did that , when the user clicks on the item of  the recyclerview it starts a intent to the next page and return the selected object to the next page . I already have the clickListener and i used some PutExtras too send the data

Comment: @FahadBinAsif Thank you for the heads up , it still works with the for loop because i dont use a for loop it wont update each time by id . I solved it by deleting all items and adding new items with the generated UUID . It was crushing when editing because some items had no ID so for loop cannot skip to next item that has an ID

Comment: Glad, it worked out, could you please post this as an answer so other community members will better understand.